# Extract Raw Video Data From WebRTC?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, webrtc

I have a video being streamed over WebRTC. I wish to extract the ***raw*** video data -- as delivered by the server (byte for byte)

The reason for this is I want to read the PTS timestamps from the video in order to determine how long as live stream has been playing

I can utilize the `MediaRecorder` API and record the `MediaStream` I'm getting back from the `RTCPeerConnection`, however doing this re-encodes the video. When I do this I get back a WEBM file that, once parsed, has PTS values starting at 0

Is there a way to retrieve the raw data being delivered over the `RTCPeerConnection` without using a `MediaRecorder`?

Comment: I won't post an "answer" (as I don't have one) and I won't close this question (in case something changes with the spec in the future), but so far to the best of my experimenting and research it seems like the only way to do what I want is to use an `RTCDataChannel` to send the raw video data, then use Media Source Extensions to display it on the other end. If you directly wire a video to the `RTCPeerConnection` then I don't see any way to access the raw data

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jacob For the sake of my job, I went with the ugly half-solution described in my comment: instead of sending video over a WebRTC PeerConnection, I created an RTCDataChannel and sent the video in a packetized format that way. We were actually using an RTMP-to-WebRTC server to stream the video originally, so this server was simplified to just send raw RTMP packets over the RTCDataChannel and I wrote an RTMP transmuxer in JavaScript to convert the video to ISO-BMFF on the fly for playback.

Comment: Ok, is setting up the RCTDataChannel similar to setting up the peer connection?

Comment: @Jacob *very similar*, although it weirdly requires a PeerConnection to be set up to do it (although that PeerConnection doesn't have to send any audio or video data): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel